# Upgrading from Drupal 7.41 CiviCRM 4.3 to 4.6.9 returns Queue runner must be configured before execution

Tags: upgrade

The queue looks like this;
[Error: undefined]
Exception: "Queue runner must be configured before execution."

```
#0 /home/leavenco/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Queue/ErrorPolicy.php(106): CRM_Queue_Page_AJAX::{closure}()
#1 /home/leavenco/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Queue/Page/AJAX.php(54): CRM_Queue_ErrorPolicy->call(Object(Closure))
#2 [internal function](): CRM_Queue_Page_AJAX::runNext()
#3 /home/leavenco/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(278): call_user_func((Array:2))
#4 /home/leavenco/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(86): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:4))
#5 /home/leavenco/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(54): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:5))
#6 /home/leavenco/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/civicrm.module(489): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:5))
#7 [internal function](): civicrm_invoke("upgrade", "queue", "ajax", "runNext")
#8 /home/leavenco/public_html/includes/menu.inc(527): call_user_func_array("civicrm_invoke", (Array:4))
#9 /home/leavenco/public_html/index.php(21): menu_execute_active_handler()
#10 {main}
```

---

Clearing the cache got me through the Queue error, thanks.

Now I'm getting the following, which may somehow be related:
FieldException: "Cannot change an existing field's type."

```
#0 /home/leavenco/public_html/sites/all/modules/features/includes/features.field.inc(175): field_update_field((Array:11))
#1 [internal function](): field_features_rebuild("events_calendar_feature", "field")
#2 /home/leavenco/public_html/sites/all/modules/features/features.module(516): call_user_func_array("field_features_rebuild", (Array:2))
#3 /home/leavenco/public_html/sites/all/modules/features/features.module(871): features_invoke("field", "features_rebuild", "events_calendar_feature")
#4 /home/leavenco/public_html/sites/all/modules/features/features.module(893): _features_restore("rebuild", (Array:0))
#5 /home/leavenco/public_html/sites/all/modules/features/features.module(229): features_rebuild()
#6 [internal function](): features_flush_caches()
#7 /home/leavenco/public_html/includes/module.inc(934): call_user_func_array("features_flush_caches", (Array:0))
#8 /home/leavenco/public_html/includes/common.inc(7625): module_invoke_all("flush_caches")
#9 /home/leavenco/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Utils/System/DrupalBase.php(294): drupal_flush_all_caches()
#10 /home/leavenco/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Upgrade/Form.php(728): CRM_Utils_System_DrupalBase->flush()
#11 [internal function](): CRM_Upgrade_Form::doIncrementalUpgradeFinish(Object(CRM_Queue_TaskContext), "4.4.5", "4.4.4", "4.6.9", "/tmp/civicrm-post-upgradex9Pctt")
#12 /home/leavenco/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Queue/Task.php(88): call_user_func_array((Array:2), (Array:5))
#13 /home/leavenco/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Queue/Runner.php(214): CRM_Queue_Task->run(Object(CRM_Queue_TaskContext))
#14 /home/leavenco/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Queue/Page/AJAX.php(52): CRM_Queue_Runner->runNext(TRUE)
#15 /home/leavenco/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Queue/ErrorPolicy.php(106): CRM_Queue_Page_AJAX::{closure}()
#16 /home/leavenco/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Queue/Page/AJAX.php(54): CRM_Queue_ErrorPolicy->call(Object(Closure))
#17 [internal function](): CRM_Queue_Page_AJAX::runNext()
#18 /home/leavenco/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(278): call_user_func((Array:2))
#19 /home/leavenco/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(86): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:13))
#20 /home/leavenco/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(54): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:5))
#21 /home/leavenco/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/civicrm.module(489): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:5))
#22 [internal function](): civicrm_invoke("upgrade", "queue", "ajax", "runNext")
#23 /home/leavenco/public_html/includes/menu.inc(527): call_user_func_array("civicrm_invoke", (Array:4))
#24 /home/leavenco/public_html/index.php(21): menu_execute_active_handler()
#25 {main}
```

Answer (score 3):

I was able to fix it by clearing the CiviCRM cache, and then re-starting the update.

I had been using the CiviCRM Clear All Caches Drupal module, but I'm not sure if it had cleared everything, as I had an error related to that module.  As a result, I emptied the civicrm_cache table directly in the database, using phpMyAdmin.

I just got the same error today, myself, when doing an upgrade from CiviCRM 4.6.3 to 4.6.9.  This thread was one of the things that suggested this solution to me: https://www.drupal.org/node/2155689.

If this (or another) solutions works for you, you may want to update your other post about this as well: http://letmeask.co/foxfeedspro/details/item_115876/upgrading-from-drupal-7-41-civicrm-4-3-to-4-6-9-returns-queue-runner-must-b/.  Hope it works for you!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion of clearing the cache using PHPMyAdmin.  That got me through the Queue error.  Now when I run the update I get the following, which may also be related to the previous error:

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem ([Error: undefined] Exception: "Queue runner must be configured before execution.") when trying to upgrade from 4.4.7 to 4.6.10 - I ended up using Drush to complete the upgrade (drush @site.env civicrm-upgrade-db) but found that I had a fatal error about not being able to create the files/civicrm directory (which already existed of course).  The error message prompted me to clear the 'config_backend' field in the civicrm_domain table which I duly did.

```
Error: Could not create directory: /srv/bindings/aacaad9724834919b5c78d62579e7186/files/civicrm.<p>If you have moved an existing CiviCRM installation from one location or server to another there are several steps you will need to follow. They are detailed on this CiviCRM wiki page - <a href="http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Moving+an+Existing+Installation+to+a+New+Server+or+Location"  target="_blank" class="crm-doc-link no-popup" title="Opens documentation in a new window.">(learn more...)</a>. A fix for the specific problem that caused this error message to be displayed is to set the value of the config_backend column in the civicrm_domain table to NULL. However we strongly recommend that you review and follow all the steps in that document.</p>Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error.       [error]
```

After running a quick "update civicrm_domain set config_backend = '';" and rerunning the drush civicrm-upgrade-db the upgrade completed successfully.